# Not able to add data through with column using case statement pyspark

Tags: pyspark, azure-databricks

Code like as below:
#To get deal keys

schema of lt_online:

```
root
 |-- FT/RT: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Country: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Charge_Type: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Tariff_Loc: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Charge_No: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Status: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Validity_from: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Validity_to: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Range_Basis: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Limited_Parties: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Charge_Detail: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Freetime_Unit: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Freetime: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Count_Holidays: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Majeure: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Start_Event: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Same/Next_Day: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Next_Day_if_AFTER: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Availability_Date: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Route_Group: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Route_Code: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Origin: string (nullable = true)
 |-- LoadZone: string (nullable = true)
 |-- FDischZone: string (nullable = true)
 |-- PODZone: string (nullable = true)
 |-- FDestZone: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Equipment_Group: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Equipment_Type: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Range_From: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Range_To: void (nullable = true)
 |-- Cargo_Type: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Commodity: string (nullable = true)
 |-- SC_Group: string (nullable = true)
 |-- SC_Number: string (nullable = true)
 |-- IMO: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Shipper_Group: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Cnee_Group: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Direction: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Service: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Haulage: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Transport_Type: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Option1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Option2: string (nullable = true)
 |-- 1st_of_Route_Group: string (nullable = true)
 |-- 1st_of_LoadZone: string (nullable = true)
 |-- 1st_of_FDischZone: string (nullable = true)
 |-- 1st_of_PODZone: string (nullable = true)
 |-- 1st_of_FDestZone: string (nullable = true)
 |-- 1st_of_Equipment_Group: string (nullable = true)
 |-- 1st_of_SC_Group: string (nullable = true)
 |-- 1st_of_Shipper_Group: string (nullable = true)
 |-- 1st_of_Cnee_Group: string (nullable = true)
```

pyspark code as below     df=lt_online.withColumn("dealkeys",lit('')).withColumn("dealAttributes",lit(''))

```
    start=[]
    
    start_dict={}
    dealatt=["Charge_No","Status","Validity_from","Validity_to"]
    
    
    dealkeys=["Charge_Type","Direction"]
    for index,row in lt_online.toPandas().iterrows():
        start=[]
        start_dict={}
        
        key = row['Charge_No']
        for i in dealatt:
        #final = row[i]
            start_dict[i]=row[i]
        
        df_deal_att = df.withColumn('dealkeys', when(col('Charge_No') == key , str(start_dict)).otherwise(col('dealkeys')))
        
        
        for i in dealkeys:
            #key = row['Charge_No']
            final = {"keyname" : i,"value" : row[i],"description":".."}
            start.append(final)
        #final_val= {"value" : row['Charge_Type']}
    #start.append(final_val)
    #df3=lt_online.withColumn("new_column",str(start))
        print(key,start_dict)
        df3 = df_deal_att.withColumn('dealAttributes', when(col('Charge_No') == key , str(start)).otherwise(col('dealAttributes')))
```

when i run DF3 dataframe dealAttributes and dealkeys old data got blank and latest record only inserted.
Please see the screenshot

[image]

Comment: Please provide the schema for `lt_online` dataframe.

Comment: updated in question itself

Comment: what i understand is ,if we have only one record in dataframe will update with given string, if dataframe has more than one record then will update only last row,first row become blank.attached results in sceenshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `lt_online` dataframe is large, I have selected only the required columns from it. The following is the schema of the `lt_online` dataframe that I have selected.

[image]

The problem arrises because you are not changing `df` in place, but assigning it to `df_deal_att`. This will update `df_deal_att` (also df3) only for the current row in loop (because df is not changing in the entire process). Using `df_deal_att.show()` inside the loop will help in understanding this.

[image]

Use the following code instead to get the desired output:

```
for index,row in lt_online.toPandas().iterrows():
    start=[]
    start_dict={}
        
    key = row['Charge_No']
    for i in dealatt:
        start_dict[i]=row[i]
    
    #ASSIGN TO df INSTEAD OF df_deal_att 
    df = df.withColumn('dealkeys', when(col('Charge_No') == key , str(start_dict)).otherwise(col('dealkeys')))

    for i in dealkeys:

        final = {"keyname" : i,"value" : row[i],"description":".."}
        start.append(final)
        
    #USE df and ASSIGN TO df INSTEAD OF USING df_deal_att AND ASSIGNING TO df3
    df = df.withColumn('dealAttributes', when(col('Charge_No') == key , str(start)).otherwise(col('dealAttributes')))
```

Assigning the `df` dataframe after adding the column value based on condition to `df` itself (instead of using `df_deal_att` or `df3`) helps in solving the issue. The following image reflects the output achieved after using the above code.

[image]

Comment: Greate really thanks for ur efforts ..I though can not change dataframe  df once we created ..